# Python: conditionally delete elements from list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of tuples:

```
x = [(1,2), (3,4), (7,4), (5,4)]
```

Of all tuples that share the second element, I want to preserve the tuple with the largest first element:

```
y = [(1,2), (7,4)]
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Python?

---

Thanks for the answers.

- The tuples could be two-element lists instead, if that makes a difference.
- All elements are nonnegative integers.
- I like the current answers. I should really learn more about what `collections` has to offer!

Comment: Do you need to retain the order of the tuples; that is, if the original is `[(a, b), (x, y)]`, then the output must have `[(a, b), (x, y)]` as the order, or is `[(x, y), (a, b)]` acceptable? Do you need to retain the order of the integers within the tuples; that is, is `[(b, a), (y, x)]` acceptable?

Comment: The order within tuples must be preserved. The order among tuples in the list should be preserved, but they can easily be sorted using `y.sort()` which will operate on the first element of each tuple.

Comment: @Steve I believe your assertion that the order of appearance of tuples in the list be preserved contradicts declaring they may also be sorted using `sort()`, unless there is an unstated assumption in your question that the input list is sorted by the first element of the tuples.

Comment: What I meant was, *if* `y` were not sorted, it could easily become sorted.

Comment: @Steve Let's be concrete. Assume your input list is `x = [(7, 4), (1, 2), (5, 3)]`. (If we can't assume this, please state so in your question.) Then, is a proposed solution which returns `y = [(1, 2), (5, 3), (7, 4)]` acceptable, or is the only valid answer `y = [(7, 4), (1, 2), (5, 3)]`?

Comment: For this SO question, I welcome either, but for my application, I need it sorted (i.e., `[(1, 2), (5, 3), (7, 4)]`). So what I was saying was that if an answer yielded `y = [(7, 4), (1, 2), (5, 3)]`, then simply do `y.sort()`.

Comment: @Steve, my answer and pillmunchers answer both get taken out without modification if the items to compare will be a list. Any list will compare as less than any tuple. The solution would be to cast to a tuple or list uniformly but that would get awkward. Gnibbler's answer is probably best for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to Aaron's answer

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = [(1,2), (3,4), (7,4), (5,4)]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for v,k in x:
...   d[k] = max(d[k],v) 
... 
>>> y=[(k,v) for v,k in d.items()]
>>> y
[(1, 2), (7, 4)]
```

note that the order is not preserved with this method. To preserve the order use this instead

```
>>> y = [(k,v) for k,v in x if d[v]==k]
>>> y
[(1, 2), (7, 4)]
```

here is another way. It uses more storage, but has less calls to max, so it may be faster

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in x:
...   d[v].append(k)
... 
>>> y = [(max(k),v) for v,k in d.items()]
>>> y
[(1, 2), (7, 4)]
```

Again, a simple modification preserves the order

```
>>> y = [(k,v) for k,v in x if max(d[v])==k]
>>> y
[(1, 2), (7, 4)]
```

Answer (score 5):

use `collections.defaultdict`

```
import collections

max_elements = collections.defaultdict(tuple)

for item in x:
    if item > max_elements[item[1]]:
        max_elements[item[1]] = item

y = max_elements.values()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was already tinkering with your earlier answer which did work for my particular case. May I ask why you changed it?

Comment: @Steve, this only iterates once and will use much less memory for a larger list. All in all, it's much better.

Comment: Thanks. I would upvote, but SO is locking me out because I upvoted, then canceled (before I could fully understand the answer), then thought I could re-upvote.

Comment: As it currently stands, this gives me the following error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` for the line `if item[0] > max_elements[item[1]][0]:` when attempting to use it with the value of `x` shown in the question.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Your fix got rid of the `TypeError` I pointed out, but your solution doesn't preserve tuple order. e.g. It's gives the same result for both `x = [(1,2), (3,4), (7,4), (5,4)]` and `x = [(3,4), (7,4), (5,4), (1,2)]`, namely `[(1, 2), (7, 4)]`.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Sorry, ignore my last comment. @Steve just let me know that preserving order isn't important.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make the assumption that tuples with identical second elements appear in contiguous order in the original list `x`, you can leverage [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
import operator

def max_first_elem(x):
    groups = itertools.groupby(x, operator.itemgetter(1))
    y = [max(g[1]) for g in groups]
    return y
```

Note that this will guarantee preservation of the order of the groups (by the second tuple element), if that is a desired constraint for the output.

Answer (score 0):

My own attempt, slightly inspired by aaronsterling:

(oh yeah, all elements are nonnegative)

```
def processtuples(x):
    d = {}
    for item in x:
        if x[0] > d.get(x[1],-1):
            d[x[1]] = x[0]

    y = []
    for k in d:
        y.append((d[k],k))
    y.sort()
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> x = [(1,2), (3,4), (7,4), (5,4)]
>>> for a, b in x:
...     d[b] = max(d[b], (a, b))
...
>>> d.values()
[(1, 2), (7, 4)
```